# How to fetch multiple Images into blade in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6

I have a form to upload multiple images. I have stored multiple image names into database while in Laravel, I'm using local storage **storage/upload** to upload my images.

Now I want to call them one by one. The solution I had in my mind didn't work.
I need logic to call all images.

Controller

```
public function multiStepStore(Request $request)
{
    if($request->hasFile('photos')) {
        $files = $request->file('photos');
        foreach ($files as $file) {
            $filename = $file->getClientOriginalName();
            $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
            Storage::disk('local')->put($filename,  File::get($file));
            $filepath[] = $filename; // Store all Images into array
            $getAllImages = collect($filepath)->implode(',');
        }
    }
}
```

Blade

```
<tr>
 <td>Location</td>
 <td>{{ $row->location}}</td>
</tr>

<tr>
 <td>Images</td>
  <td>
    @foreach( (array) $row->img_path as $img)
       <img src=" asset('storage/uploads/' .{{ $img }}">
    @endforeach
</tr>
```

The output is just a broken image thumbnail.
How can I get all images?

Comment: Your multiStepStore controller works fine?

Comment: @STA
Yes I' m getting all column values including "img_path" that stores the names for all images.
Now I want to show all images into blade.

Comment: Make `php artisan storage:link` then `{{ asset('storage/uploads/' . $img) }}`

Comment: You stored your image inside `/storage/uploads`, which is not a `public` directory. The public directory is `/storage/app/public`. Now `php artisan storage:link` will work

Comment: @STA
It's showing broken thumbnail. 
In console, it returns all the stored image names in link like 
http:://(webite)/storage/uploads/img1,img2,img3

Comment: I know there is app directory under storage but I created my own directory on root with named "uploads" that's why not calling the directory storage/app/public

Comment: Because `php artisan storage:link` make a symbolic link with `/public` to `storage/app/public`. so you need to place your files `storage/app/public/uploads`

Comment: @STA
It's still not fixed after updating storage directory to storage/app/public/uploads.
This is error what I' m seeing in console
"<img src="http://127.0.0.1:8000/storage/uploads/gmail-icon.png,gmail.jpg,gmailhero.jpg">"

Comment: Did you save all images in a string field?

Comment: Can you access now? http://127.0.0.1:8000/storage/uploads/gmail-icon.png

Comment: Yeah. this link works..

Comment: The link works mean, `php artisan storage:link` build the symbolic link successfully, $row->img_path is an array or string?

Comment: Yes, that's an array that I stored into database after converting into string.

Comment: Actually you stored all your images in a single stiring,  separate by comma. This is not a good programming practice. By the way,  I'll give you an answer,  hoe to solve

Comment: @STA
Thanks. If you could share alternative approach that would be grateful.

Comment: store per image in dirrerent row

Comment: @STA
In my project, each user is allowed to submit 15 images max. According to your approach, I have to create 15 image columns per row against one user. Now, let's say If no of users are 200 then as per my knowledge, it would decrease the efficiency of database.

Your thoughts ?

Comment: if you have few data you can follow this way. But if you have more data then it takes time to load, then make string to an array. For few data this is enough

Comment: Cool. Thanks.........

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You stored your image inside `/storage/uploads`, which is not a `public` directory. The public directory is `/storage/app/public`. move all your `/storage/uploads` files to `/storage/app/public/uploads`, then create a symbolic link as :

```
php artisan storage:link
```

Change your blade code like this :

```
@php 
    $x = explode (",", $row->img_path);
@endphp
@foreach($x as $key => $val)
     <img src="{{ asset('storage/uploads/' . $val) }}">
@endforeach
```